# Transform cube face in the z up direction to vertice above (need automation method)

Tags: modeling

My scene currently has 2 objects in it from imported gis data sets.

- The first object contains a series of cubes, think building shapes.
- The second object contains a series of vertices that define the z up height. One vertice for each cube and is roughly placed in the center of each cube top face (building elevation)

Question:

What would be the fastest method to snap a cube top face to the above vertice if you had a few hundred cubes? (The snap to vertex is not workable because of the number of verts in the scene)

I have seen a drop to the ground script for objects so I think there may be addon for gis data out there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A picture would clarify it. Are the cubes all the same? Are the vertices really snapped to the top of the cubes, not the bottom?

Answer (score 2):

You may be asking for the DupliVerts feature.

In this case, the general steps would be:

1. Move the origin of the cube to the center of its top face;
2. First select the cube, then select the vertex cloud object, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> > **Object**;
3. Keep the parent object (vertex cloud) selected, go to **Properties > Object Data > Duplication**, select '**Verts**". As shown in the image below.

[image: vertex_snap]

P.S.: Remember to keep their origins staying at same location.